# Add value to array in reducer

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add to an array in my object, I'm passing the id and the value to add:

```
case ADD_ACHIEVEMENT:
  return [
    {
      id: action.id,
      achievements: [...state.achievements, action.label]
    },
    ...state
  ]
```

Initial state:

```
const initialState = [
  {
    date: "Fri 1st",
    enjoyments: [],
    achievements: [],
    id: 0
  },
  {
    date: "Fri 2",
    enjoyments: [],
    achievements: [],
    id: 1
 },
```

How can I add the value in the reducer?

EDIT: Sorry I'm new to redux I might not be explaining myself properly. I'd like to update the `achievement`s array for the `id` that I pass in the `action`. My achievements array is just an array of strings. I would just like to add another entry.

Getting sytax error:

Syntax error: C:/sites/CalendarRedux/src/reducers/days.js: Unexpected token, expected , (62:11)

```
case ADD_ACHIEVEMENT:
  return state.map(day => {
    if (day.id === action.id) {
      return Object.assign({}, day, {
        achievements: [
          ...day.achievements,
          action.label,
        ]
      }; <<<<<<< line 62
    }

    return day;
 });
```

Comment: I am very confused by what you are trying to do. So you have an array of objects in your state, and you want to update or add a new object to that array ? There is no `state.achievements`, and your initialState is an array ?

Comment: It looks like you are adding it in your top snippet. I see you returning a new array with an element added. Is that code failing? Or more generally, what is the difference between what you are getting and what you want?

Comment: @G4bri3l yes thats correct. I need to add an entry to the achievements array for the appropriate id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case ADD_ACHIEVEMENT:
  return state.map(item => {
    if (item.id === action.id) {
      return Object.assign({}, item, {
        achievements: [
          ...item.achievements,
          action.label,
        ]
      });
    }

    return item;
 });
```

Given your comment you basically want to update the item in your array that matches the `id` passed by the action. This is one way to do it, basically you map each item to itself if you don't wanna update it, and you update the one that matches the `id`. The error you were making was trying to access `state.achievements` while instead you needed to access the `achievements` of the specific item.

Comment: Edited, just a missing parenthesis